# MongoDB run update from shell

Tags: mongodb, shell

```
mongo 10.78.13.144/staging --eval="db.companies.update({'internal':'internal.domain.com'},{$set:{'internal':'staging.internal.domain.com'}});"
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: 10.78.13.144/portal_staging
Mon Nov 18 08:59:59.116 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

This command executes just fine directly in the mongo shell but not from outside. We tried various ways to execute this command but all throw the same error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Comment: What do you mean with "outside"? Are you executing the command from the bash? Maybe you just need to escape the "$" in "$set"...

Answer (score 1):

`$set` is interpreted as a shell variable. You need to escape it:

```
--eval="db.companies.update({'internal':'internal.domain.com'},{\$set:{'internal':'staging.internal.domain.com'}});"
```